# Drinfeld quotient of 'finite' dg-categories

Tags: homotopy-theory, dg-categories

I have been reading Gonçalo Tabuada's paper [Higher K-theory via universal invariants](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0706.2420.pdf) in a seminar and the following question arose.

At one point in his construction (specifically $\S$10) he looks at the set of full dg-inclusions $\mathcal G\hookrightarrow\mathcal H$ where $\mathcal H$ is a strict finite $I$-cell, where $I$ is the usual (I suppose) set of generating cofibrations of the category **dgcat** of small dg-categories where we take Morita equivalences as the weak equivalences. The interest is in the Drinfeld quotient $\mathcal H\,/\,\mathcal G$.

The main question I have is the following: is this quotient still (weakly/Morita equivalent to) a strict finite $I$-cell? I'm not sure this is required for Tabuada's argument to hold, but it would be nice to know if we can take the quotient in the 'finite' part of **dgcat**.